# Why I can't be able to access HTTP sites?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, http, https, connectify

I'm using Connectify to make my laptop a hot-spot to use Internet on my phone. Sites which use HTTP are not being opened but sites that use HTTPS are opened. It says `error 102` What can I do about it? I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: Perhaps the Connectify software also serves as a firewall that blocks port 80 (HTTP) to force you to use HTTPS?

Comment: So what do I do? :(

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 Connectify.

Comment: Oh, lol. I didn't even realise you wrote the name of the software in your question.

Comment: As per codd's suggestion check Connectify's settings for anything that may suggest that it is blocking port 80.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually if there's an error for HTTPS requests in Desktop environment, that means the system time is incorrect or the request did not render the digital certificates of a user-requested site properly. I cannot be so sure that it does the same since internet traffic routed through your PC to mobile. Just have a look & see whether it helps. Also, I found this while googling.

- **[Firewall security settings ~ Connectify](http://support.connectify.me/entries/20313068-Firewall-Security-Settings-)**